# El HTML retornado por un array de una funcion en React esta siendo desplegado como texto en vez de renderizarse

Tags: javascript, html, array, reactjs

Tengo una función que recibe un array de objetos llamado "**parts**" y debe desplegarlos en un paragraph cada uno, entonces lo que hice fue agregar cada renglon a desplegar en celdas de un nuevo arreglo "**array**" agregandole la etiqueta HTML de paragraph al principio y el final pero al momento de ejecutar el programa recibo las etiquetas de paragraph como texto, segun tengo entendido es por no escapar los caracteres asi que agregue una función para reemplazar caracteres pero no esta funcionando:

```js
const parts = [
    {
      name: 'Fundamentals of React',
      exercises: 10
    },
    {
      name: 'Using props to pass data',
      exercises: 7
    },
    {
      name: 'State of a component',
      exercises: 14
    }
  ]

    function escapeHtmlChars(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

const Content = (props) => {
    let array = []
    for (let i = 0; i < props.parts.length; i++) {  
    array.push('<p>'+props.parts[i].name+' '+props.parts[i].exercises+'</p>')
    }
    array.forEach(value =>{
        array[value]= escapeHtmlChars(value)
    })
    return(
    <div>
    {array}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Y la función Content es llamada de este modo:

```js
const App = () => {
      const course = 'Half Stack application development'
      return (
        <div>
        <Header course={course}/>
        <Content parts={parts}/>
        <Total parts={parts}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Estoy usando React, una disculpa si algo esta mal en el formato, no me quedo claro como plasmarlo en StackOverflow.

Comment: debes usar innerHTML o textContent para agregar tu código html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías simplificar tu función Content a algo como esto:

```
const Content = (props) => {
  return (
   <div>
    {props.parts.map(part => (
      <p>{`${part.name} ${part.exercises}`}</p>
    ))}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto